# Django won't serve on Apache/Fedora 23 VM since i changed PCs

Tags: django, apache, vmware, fedora

I recently got a new PC and put my Fedora 23/Apache VM on it.  I had Django site serving successfully previously through this VM before switching PCs.  Now when i run:

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```

i don't appear to get errors, but when i put the ip address (inet, non-loopback) in my web browser, nothing happens, no data is sent.

my etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

my httpd.conf file:

```
ServerName localhost
```

when i run 'hostname -f', i get "localhost".

is there another IP address i need to add to any of the above files in order to get this working? i looked at other posts related to this, but couldn't figure out which IP address, if any, to add.

help?

Answer (score 0):

actually, it looks like the firewall never got permanently disabled, so when i did:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
```

it booted up fine.